# What is the proper SSD for DEll Latitude E5550?

Tags: laptop, hard-disk, ssd, upgrade

I want to know what is the proper SSD for my Dell Latitude E5550 i7 5th gen., 8GB RAM. Right now I have a HDD and wish to upgrade my computer a little bit. I found the user's manual and the [spec sheet](https://www.dell.com/learn/us/en/uschn1/shared-content%7Edata-sheets%7Een/documents%7Ecsg-en-xx-all-latitude-15-e5550-spec-sheet.pdf) online, where the storage options are described (right column of the image). The storage capacity is clear enough, nevertheless, I don't know whether if I can install any SATA SSD, i.e., SATA II or III, or maybe there's a limit related with the SSD speed. What dimensions of SSD are compatible and which will be the best?

Thanks in advanced.[image: Storage Options]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All 2.5in SSD's should work, and at full speed. I personally love the Crucial MX500, since it's cheap and availible in packeges up to 4TB. I don't reccomend using the 4TB model though, since that may be limited to 2TB if your BIOS does not support GPT.

Comment: Their CPU is i7 5th gen, their BIOS does support EFI boot and GPT.